# Using unconventional programming languages for scientific computation

Tags: languages

Note: the following post may include controversial opinions, so please
note that they are only my opinions, and not intended to offend
anyone.

I'm being programming in some form or the other since around 1999. I
initially used R, and then later, around 2004, mostly switched to
Python.

For many scientific applications, for example, simulation,
including such things as MCMC, both R and Python are too slow and need
to be sped up. The usual way of doing so is by extending with C or
C++. For both R and Python, this is what I did, using R's C API with
C++, and the Boost Python library with Python.

However, for various reasons, this combination is not the ideal
solution. What is important in programming, particularly algorithms?
Expressiveness and speed, which are of course related. The more
expressive a language, the faster one can write in it.

1) As far as expressiveness goes, neither R nor Python are really
ideal for writing scientific algorithms in my opinion. They do not
closely map to the underlying algorithm. However, they are both
considerably better than C++.

2) I enjoy writing in Python, which is a pleasant language, though as
noted above it is not ideal for algorithmic work. However, when one has
to work with a Python/C++ combination because of speed issues, this
mix becomes considerably less pleasant to work with. What usually
happens is that I first write in Python, and once I have something
that is working well, often discover that it is too slow (for some
subjective value of too slow). I then face the decision of whether to
spend some unreasonable amount of time rewriting it in C++, or put up
with the slowness. In hindsight I often feel I might have been better
off putting up with the slowness, especially as the speedups obtained
are unpredictable. Also, the Boost Python interface between the two is
a significant maintenance headache, and having code in two very
different languages glued together like this is just distracting. No
criticism of Boost Python intended, it is as powerful an interface as
one could imagine, and pretty much just works most of the time.

Now, in an ideal world, with unlimited time and resources, neither of
these problems would be a major deal. However, in scientific projects
I have worked on, I've had the following experience.

Whether or not I have collaborators on the project, I always seem to
wind up doing the vast majority of the computing. In a total of 5
significant projects, I only had substantial participation from one
people on one project. That one person did more than pull his weight;
he did as much as me or more. However, in all other cases, including
projects with multiple collaborators, I've done (virtually) all the
computational work. While I can say that I have not been blessed with
the best collaborators (it seems to be a mixture of laziness and
incompetence) it is not clear to me whether this state of affairs is
likely to change in the future.

Computational scientific work is an enormous amount of effort, and if
I can't change how my collaborators behave, I can change the way I
work. The most important improvement would be to get things done more
quickly. Which brings me to the main consideration here, which is that
switching languages to something less orthodox may help. Based on past
research, the most likely candidates in order of likelihood are Common
Lisp and Ocaml. I've been thinking about this for years, but recently
have been thinking about it more seriously.

As far I can tell, few people use either CL or Ocaml for scientific
computation. On searching this site, I found two references to CL (one
was mine) and one to Ocaml (mine). I've had a couple of encouraging
contacts over the years with adventurous people working on the
fringe. In 2008 I came across a [book
review](http://www.amazon.com/review/RVC91D51ZA20U) of Peter Seibel's
"Practical Common Lisp" (which I own), by Tamas K. Papp. This caught
my attention, since it was one of the few mentions of scientific computing
for Lisp that I had come across on the net. I wrote to Tamas, who immediately
replied helpfully and encouragingly. To quote him

> My programming productivity probably increased tenfold with Lisp, but
>   that took about a year to happen and I am still learning (I was doing
>   quite well after 2 months though).  So if you are working on something
>   time-critical, then postpone the switch.
>
> You should consider asking folks on c.l.l, I am not the only one who
>   knows about these things, others do scientific computing on Lisp.

He also has a [blog](http://tkpapp.blogspot.in/) and [a GitHub
page](https://github.com/tpapp).

Another person I briefly corresponded with (in December 2006) was [Ira
Kalet](http://faculty.washington.edu/ikalet/), who has used Common
Lisp in the context of radiation oncology.

Perhaps there are others who do scientific computing on Lisp, but I
don't know of anyone.

The most common problem people cite with CL is the lack of
libraries. This is a severe problem in general purpose computing, but
may not be so much so in scientific computing, particularly from the
ground up implementations of algorithms. Specifically, I can get by
most of the time with a basic math library, including probability
distribution functions, a multidimensional array library, and a
basic set of containers e.g. map, set, list etc. as found in the C++ and
Python standard libraries.

I know even less about Ocaml than I do about CL, but threw that in as an
alternative. It is supposedly very fast, has one free implementation
by French researchers, and seems like the most viable of the ML family
of languages for scientific computing.

To conclude, I'm wondering if others have experience with this, and
what thoughts they have, if any.

EDIT: I'm mostly interested in first hand experience, in the context of the issues I've discussed above. E.g. if you used to use Python and C++ (or R and C++) and moved to a more obscure language, I'd be most interested in hearing about your experiences.

Comment: Stack exchange is for asking questions, not for posting life stories! Your question seems to be "Are there any scientific computing projects using Common Lisp or OCaml", right?

Comment: Agreed, this reads a little bit more like a blog post, but I do like the premise.  Any chance you could try and reduce this to 2-3 paragraphs?

Comment: Also agreed. Commentary and personal experience is good when it supports the main question; too much detail can swamp out the main points. If you can condense your question, I think it'd be easier to read and it would get more targeted, higher quality responses.

Comment: @AronAhmadia: I was trying to fill in context. Personally, I prefer discursive questions, which fill in background and details, but maybe I'm in the minority. Do you have any specific suggestions about what to remove?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: In the "ideal world" you mention mid-way through it would be all hand-optimized assembly...  Sounds dismal to me!

Comment: @FaheemMitha: The best thing I think you could do to improve your question is to make the question you're asking clear. It seems like you're telling a story about your experiences (which is all right), and then at the end, you bury the question as a statement at the end of your story. ("To conclude, I'm wondering...") The best thing you can do is to make that part a question, so people skimming your question can readily identify what you're asking. I had to go back a couple times to figure it out.

Comment: @meawoppl: I think you misunderstand my comment. In the "ideal world" in question, expressiveness and performance wouldn't matter because we would have all the time and resources in the world. "in an ideal world, with unlimited time and resources, neither of these problems would be a major deal." So, everyone might be happy using Python, for example.

Comment: Upon rereading, I think I take issue with the mixing in of your experiences and subjective opinions of what the answer should be, instead of a purely objective query.  I'm not going to edit your post, but in the future, try to keep this in mind when asking questions on this site.

Comment: @Szabolcs - My point is that the question itself contains subjective statements, which is less okay than a subjective answer (which would have been one way to tackle this question).  I'd like to avoid dragging things out in comments, if anybody has more to say on this please bring it to chat or meta.

Comment: @AronAhmadia Sorry about that, I'll remove the comments.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Please don't. I appreciated your kind and supportive comments.

Comment: I've had some fun working with lua as the glue for high performance c++ code. Lua talks to C/C++ quite readily using a more convenient and leightwight interface than python

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I've been mulling the question over the past day, and the question isn't a good one for the format. (It's been flagged as not constructive, and after looking at the accompanying blurb, I have to agree.) The site isn't geared towards questions that boil down to "What's your opinion on (and experience with) using unconventional languages in scientific computing?" I think it's an important question to ask, though, and the answers are good, so perhaps it could be salvaged by instead asking if people have improved their productivity by using unconventional languages.

Answer (score 18):

We developed [Julia](http://julialang.org/) for *exactly* the reasons raised. There was just no good high level scientific computing language that also gave good enough performance, that you didn't have to keep rewriting parts of your code in C/Fortran. The design of julia has a fair bit of lisp influence, so you may find it to your liking, while your collaborators can just treat it like a matlab or R if they don't care about the functional parts. The downside is that the language is new, and does not yet have all the libraries one would need for day-to-day usage.

Mark, would love to add julia to your benchmark to see how we fare. Do hop on over to our mailing list and let us know what you'd like to see in julia so that it is more useful to you.

Comment: That looks beautiful! I will definitely check this out for my own work. Currently I use python for all my work in theoretical condensed matter, just because the time gained by having fast C++ code is negated by the time spent writing in C++ in the first place :)

Answer (score 9):

[The speed, size and dependability of programming languages](http://blog.gmarceau.qc.ca/2009/05/speed-size-and-dependability-of.html) does a really good job of wrapping up a lot of different concerns expressed in your "question."  It compares the speed and codebase size of a bunch of implementations of the same benchmarks across 33 languages!

I have become a Python lover mainly because it is much more common to have excess computing time than excess time to program.  I am more than willing to squander CPU cycles than sacrifice a wedge of time that could be devoted to something more interesting.

Also, +1 on Julia.  I think I may switch to it when it becomes a bit more stable and widely supported i.e. when standard modules are wrapped for the work I like doing.

Answer (score 4):

For scientific applications of OCaml, see for example

- [OCaml for scientists](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/ocaml_for_scientists/)
- [a presentation of OCaml for scientists](http://romain.bardou.fr/slides/caml060711.pdf)

For Lisp in science, see for example

- [SciCL](http://www.siginf.com/13023.html)
- [a presentation about scientific computing in Lisp](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~didier/research/verna.06.labri-slides.pdf)
- [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) (statistical computing in Clojure, which is a Lisp dialect)

I am sure there are many more references. However, I cannot cite any major research project in which computational work was done in either OCaml or Lisp. Choosing either one means working in relative isolation.

You may also be interested in [Julia](http://julialang.org/), a new language for scientific computing currently under development, with clear Lisp influences.

Comment: I should perhaps have made it more clear that I'm mostly interested in first hand experience. I'll edit my question to reflect this.